# Real time update from a variable in php

Tags: php, curl, real-time, flush

I have this code and its working fine. It shows real time update.

```
function progress($resource,$download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded)
{
if($download_size > 0)
    $GLOBALS['progress'] = round($downloaded / $download_size  * 100);
    echo $GLOBALS['progress'];
    echo str_pad("", 1024, " ");
    flush();
    usleep(20000);
}
```

Then why this code doesn't show real time update. It shows 100 at the end of execution of script.

```
function progress($resource,$download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded)
{
if($download_size > 0)
    $GLOBALS['progress'] = round($downloaded / $download_size  * 100);
 }
if($GLOBALS['progress']) {
echo $GLOBALS['progress'];
echo str_pad("", 1024, " ");
flush();
usleep(20000);
 }
```

Actually I don't need to show real time update. What I want is to start a task when the value of $GLOBALS['progress'] is greater than 0. For ex.

```
if($GLOBALS['progress']>0){
  //start another download immediately not when the value reaches to 100  
}
```

When I am trying with 2nd version of my code it starts the task when the value is 100. I need immediately to execute a code as soon as its value reaches to 1 or greater than 0. Can anyone tell why 2nd version of my code is not working and how can I accomplish my actual task? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PHP was never designed to, and shouldn't be used as, a long running process. It's intended to start up, generate output, and die() or exit() as soon as possible. If you need a persistent data store that gets updated, *do that*, by using a genuine data store and tiny, tiny scripts that you trigger client-side via XHR, and that either fetch your values, or post update requests

Comment: Please review your opening and closing braces. You have one after your if statement, that actually closes the whole function, not that if. If I correct the braces, the code works fine.

Comment: I want to execute the code outside the function. That's why I have closed the function. Thanks. @Fenistil

Comment: It's not a long running process. I want to download two files from external server but not using curl multi. That's it :) @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: your `usleep(20000);` suggests otherwise. If you need a repeating task, write the task as a one-time action, then make a cron job for it so it runs every X seconds/minutes/hours/etc